# Result is not displayed inside the tbody using php ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am creating a simple payroll. Data is coming successfully. I checked it through `console.log` but it is not passing to the `tbody`:

**Html**

```
  <tr style="font-weight: bold">
     <td colspan="3">Extra Allowance</td>
     </tr>
     <tbody id="ps_employee_allo">

     </tbody>
```

**AJAX successfunction**

```
 success: function (data) {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         $('#ps_employee_allo').append ('<tr><td>' + data[i].dpayitem + '</td></tr>');
     }
 }
```

**php file**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select s.empname,s.bsal,s.allowance,e.payitem,d.payitem,e.amout,d.amout from salary s  join salearn e on s.id = e.salid join saldeduct d on s.id = d.salid where s.id = ? and s.empid = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$sal_id,$emp_id);
$sal_id = $_POST['sal_id'];
$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];

$stmt->bind_result($empname,$bsal,$allowance,$epayitem,$dpayitem,$eamout,$damout);

if($stmt->execute())
{
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $output = array("empname"=> $empname,"bsal"=> $bsal,"allowance"=> $allowance,"epayitem"=> $epayitem, "dpayitem"=> $dpayitem,"eamout"=> $eamout,"damout"=> $damout );
    }

    echo json_encode( $output);
}
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: the code above looks ok so far, please show some more to identify the issue.

Comment: i edited code and add php file also

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(key); // key 
    console.log(data[key]); // value 
}
```

Comment: i tried i got the error was Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1   console.log(dpayitem);

Comment: Your return data must definitely be json, so it must first become an object
Then you can easily justify them with the above code

Comment: plz send me ```console.log(data)``` in ajax success

Comment: Object
allowance: 12000
bsal: 12000
damout: 101
dpayitem: "Loan"
eamout: 100
empname: "Nishanthan"
epayitem: "BONUS"

Comment: console.log(data[dpayitem]); i passed the keyvalue sir result displayed dpayitem

Comment: Paste what you showed me with the data
This should work

Comment: empname
kishan
bsal
12000
dpayitem
Loan    it is working sir how to pass this in to   $('#ps_employee_allo').append

Comment: sir how to pass the key in to   $('#ps_employee_allo').append ('<tr><td>' + data.dpayitem + '</td></tr>'); here it is not working undefined output shown

Comment: for (var key in data) {
    console.log(key); // key 
    console.log(data[key]); // value 
}  how to this to append to  the table